# Am I not allowed to delete a ssl::stream<tcp::socket> if it has pending operations?

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost

I have a `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` with the handshake already done. I start a asynchronous read and then I delete the object (I destruct it and reset it's memory to 0xff). Then, I get a segmentation fault because Boost Asio is accessing stuff in the object that I've just deleted. When I test this with just `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` my callback is just invoked with operation aborted, which is what I expected when using ssl::stream.

The code that I used to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

template <typename T>
void debug(T& a)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); ++i)
    {
        if (i % 8 == 0) std::cout << std::endl << i << "\t";
        std::cout << unsigned(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&a)[i]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void destruct(T& a)
{
    a.~T();
    memset(&a, 0xff, sizeof(a));
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[4096];
    const char* write = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n";

    boost::asio::io_service io;
    //boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* socket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io);
    boost::asio::ssl::context ssl_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1);

    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>* socket = new boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(io, ssl_context);
    socket->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("stackoverflow.com", std::to_string(443));

    resolver.async_resolve(query, [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator result)
    {
        if (ec) throw ec;

        //socket->async_connect(*result, [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
        socket->next_layer().async_connect(*result, [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
        {
            if (ec) throw ec;

            socket->async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client, [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
            {
                if (ec) throw ec;

                boost::asio::async_write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer(write, std::string(write).size()), [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t)
                {
                    if (ec) throw ec;


                    socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 4096), [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t len)
                    {
                        if (ec) {
                            std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            debug(*socket);
                            return;
                        }

                        std::cout.write(buffer, len);

                        std::cout << std::endl << "End" << std::endl;
                    });

                    debug(*socket);
                    destruct(*socket);
                });

            }
            );
        });
    });

    io.run();

    debug(*socket);
}
```

Comment: It's funny. The way the code is written there doesn't seem to be any asynchrony. You could use synchronous calls all the way. Why is `socket` even dynamically allocated here?

Comment: @sehe It is a minimal code used to expose my issue.

Comment: Okay fair enough. It's just so much simplified, that the reason to complicate stuff is gone.

Comment: @sehe Just to make it clearer. The pasted code will crash with a segfault.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you are not:

> [Thread Safety](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html#boost_asio.reference.ssl__stream.thread_safety)
>
> Distinct objects: Safe.
>
> Shared objects: Unsafe. The application must also ensure that all asynchronous operations are performed within the same implicit or explicit strand.

---

The usual approach is to make your session ("connection") a `boost::enable_shared_from_this` derived class and bind the completion handlers to `shared_from_this()`. That way, you can just let the `shared_ptr<Session>` go out of scope, and the object will only be deleted once the last pending operation has completed (including the completion handler).

**BONUS**

Here's equivalent code, without the "false" asynchrony, with automatic lifetimes and with implicit exceptions!

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77a2b894cb260c73)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

namespace ba  = boost::asio;
namespace ssl = ba::ssl;
using ba::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    char buffer[4096];
    const char* write = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n";

    ba::io_service io;
    ssl::context ssl_context(ssl::context::tlsv1);
    ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket(io, ssl_context);

    socket.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_none);

    tcp::resolver resolver(io);
    tcp::resolver::query query("stackoverflow.com", std::to_string(443));

    auto result = resolver.resolve(query);
    socket.next_layer().connect(*result);

    socket.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);

    /*size_t ignore = */ba::write(socket, ba::buffer(write, std::string(write).size()));

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    size_t len = socket.read_some(ba::buffer(buffer, 4096), ec);
    if (ec) {
        std::cout << ec.message() << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout.write(buffer, len);
    }

    std::cout << "\nEnd\n";
}
```

Comment: Added equivalent code, much simplified [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77a2b894cb260c73)

Comment: Could you help me interpret the quoted text? I did not understand how it implies that the destruction would not be allowed if there are pending asynchronous operations.

Comment: Mmm. Technically, indeed, you're right. I did assume that your real code was less contrived and involved real asynchrony. Yes, running the destructor will in principle _just_ cancel any pending operations. *BUT* running the destructor _unsynchronized_ leads to undefined behaviour. Of course your original sample doesn't show any of this happening.

Comment: Your suggestion of using shared_ptrs (and cancel() instead of deleting the socket) solves my problem. Yet, I will keep researching as I am still not sure if this is not a bug.